# XJC undefined 'soapenc:Array' (Java)

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, xjc

I've been tasked to integrate with a 3rd party web service.  In their WSDL, they declare arrays as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="ITransEazSvcservice" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:ns1="urn:LandairSvcIntf">
  <types>
    <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="urn:LandairSvcIntf">
...
      <complexType name="CustomItemArray">
        <complexContent>
          <restriction base="soapenc:Array">
            <sequence/>
            <attribute xmlns:n1="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" ref="soapenc:arrayType" n1:arrayType="ns1:CustomItemRecord[]"/>
          </restriction>
        </complexContent>
      </complexType>
...
```

When I run xjc to generate code to integrate with the web service, I get the following error message:

> [ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'soapenc:Array'

and

> [ERROR] undefined attribute 'soapenc:arrayType'

What do I need to do in order to generate the the proper code to integrate with their service?  We use Java.